# How to retain all attribute data when clip two shapefile?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, shapefile, polygon, arcgis-pro

I have two shapefiles, one is soil map and another one is paddock map.
I want to label every paddocks with soil type, but I don't know how.
I tried to use **intersect** , but it created more polygon like this.
Is there any options I can try?
[image: soil map]
[image: after intersect]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does not sound like you want to Clip. Instead try [Spatial Join](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/analysis-toolbox/spatial-join.htm) to only transfer attributes:

> Joins attributes from one feature to another based on the spatial
>   relationship. The target features and the joined attributes from the
>   join features are written to the output feature class.

The geometries will not be modified